# R studio stopping script

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a script that is running since a long time, and unfortunately there is an update that I can't stop that will restart my computer, If I stop the process does all results that are stores in a data frame will be kept? or it behaves like an error and everything is lost.

Comment: Why cant you stop the update? I think it depends on your script, but my guess would be that the data.frame is lost, when you stop the script. Unless you constantly append rows to a data.frame in a loop. Then you could stop it, save the data.frame to disk or the whole workspace to an RData object, restart and somehow continue where you left.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get it well, but the data frame is a variable that will be save in your R environment, if the script already created all the data frame it will be save in your R environment until it be restarted.
If your computer restart before the creation of your data frame it won't be save.

Comment: But If I stop the process before the restart, am I going to get what was already stored in the dataframe? My idea is to stop the script save the data frame with all the values if they are still there, restart and then run again what is left

Comment: No, they will not be saved. It will be threatened as a "force stop" and will  delete all the data frame. Like a "rollback"

Comment: Actually everything that was calculated in the data frame and stored remain in the dataframe.